# HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found when try to open a php file

Tags: php, apache, xampp

Am trying to use `php` I downloaded `XAMPP` control panel `v3.2.2`set the port to listen at 8080 and I set the localhost to 8080 too and `apache` starts and runs fine.

The problem is that for any php file that I try to open by writing at my `browser:localhost/thefile'sname.php`, even though I have saved it in `C:\xampp\htdocs`, I get the error:HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found. Any ideas as to what could be causing this error to occur and how to fix it?

Comment: Return the old values and only change your apache port to listen on 4033 and your database on 80 (mysql) then quit the control panel and restart it

Comment: just so i dont screw anything up and make it worse..i should change the  the local host which currently listens on 8080 to listen on 80 and then have the apache port listen on 4033 instead of 8080?

Comment: No you dont need to type in your browser: localhost:8080 BUT localhost/yourfile.php and have the mysql listen to port 80 and your apache to port 4033

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it can't find the document it's most definitely with your apache config and your document root or possibly a .htaccess file in the document root?

check or post your apache config and check for .htaccess file.

ah also localhost will only map to port 80,  http://localhost:8080/yourfile.php